# Capifony An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command

Tags: symfony, deployment, capifony

Sorry for my english, im french.

I have issue with deployment.
I deploy one time on my server but i can't deploy a second time.
This error message :

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
> The service "assetic.helper.static" has a dependency on a non-existent service "assets.packages".
>
> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
> handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception   *
>
> [RuntimeException]                                                            *   An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.

I have no source code in my server. (Because capifony rollbacks).
Configuration is optimal because I had deploy one time in this server. But I removed all files with : rm -R ...
I have 1GB of memory.

Please, have you solution for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the command, is your services configuration.
Anything that you try to execute will throw this error.

Seems like you have some composer dependency missing, since this is from an internal service, you can try to run composer install, remove the app/cache directory manually and then try to cache clear again.

If no success check if your bundles are correctly configured at AppKernel